# Plot output of matrix function

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix function with a scalar output, and I would like to plot this as a function of one of the elements of the matrix.  The exact function isn't important, so I'll use `det` for my example:

```
>> fplot(det([x 0;0,1]),[0,1000])
Error using vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

alternatively:

```
>> x=linspace(0,1000,1001);
>> plot(det([x,0;0,1]))
Error using vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

I'm sure this is simple, and there just a trick which googling hasn't revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible (as I knew it would be) using `fplot`.  But the command has to be `fplot('det([x,0;0,1])',[0,1000])` (note the quotes).  In fact my ancient (matlab 5) paper manual says:

> "The most common mistake in using `fplot` (as well as other numerical
>   analysis functions) is forgetting to put the name of the function in
>   quotes  That is `fplot` needs to know the name of the function as a
>   character string"

Answer (score 2):

```
x=linspace(0,1000,1001);
plot(det([x,0;0,1]))
```

This is a problem: `[x,0;0,1]`

because `x` has 1001 elements so your top row (i.e. `[x,0]`) is 1002 elements and your bottom row is just 2 elements. And you're trying to vertically concatenate them i.e. the `[;]` operator. This only works if both rows have the same number of columns.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to plot so I can't recommend a fix, you'll have to explain the problem a bit better first.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'm trying to plot `det(M)` against `x`, using `M=[x,0;0,1]`.  I don't particularly want an array of all the values of x, but this appear to be how matlab builds the data for the plot.  My actual function is rather more complex, but as `det` demonstrates my problem it's a simple way to show/ask.

Comment: @ChrisH But as I explained in my solution, `M=[x,0;0,1]` makes no sense in Matlab (unless `x` is a scalar). What exactly do you mean by it?

Comment: So how do you define a matrix in which one element is a variable?  Anyway, I have found a solution, and it was, as I thought a novice mistake.

Comment: @ChrisH like that, but `x` can't be a vector as it will cause a dimension mismatch. If you defined `x=1` for example instead of `linspace` you wouldn't have gotten that error.

Comment: I don't want to define it as a vector, I want to use it as the independent variable for a plot.  The difficult I was having was that it seemed as though the only ways to do that caused it to be created as a vector (implicitly in the case of fplot).  If I didn't want to evaluate for many values of x and plot, it would be easy.